# Why am I getting this error? "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid."

Tags: deployment, gac, http-module

I have created and implemented the `IHttpModule` interface in order to use the `Session_Start` event in SharePoint 2010 (like global.asax in asp.net). I have added the `add` tag into my web.config file in the `modules` section (because I use integrated mode) and I have also deployed my DLL to GAC, but I get this error:

> The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please post the add tag you're adding to the web.config. I bet there's a problem with the format of the assembly reference.

Comment: i create a class library with vs 2010 and .net 3.5 with the strong name key file and my namespace and assembly name is "OnlineUsersHTTPModule" and my class name is "OnlineUsersModule" and i deployed the output dll to GAC and also add this tag to web.config in modules section: <add name="Test" type="OnlineUsersHTTPModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=78aac1459052cd0a" preCondition="integratedMode" />

Comment: Did you find the answer for this problem? :) I have the same problem.

Comment: yes i did. the problem was in my module tag in web.config file. so i check that again and fixed it. <add name="Test" type="OnlineUsersHTTPModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=78aac1459052cd0a" preCondition="integratedMode" />. it must be the full assembly name, not just the class name.

Comment: If you have found the solution, please post this as an answer so that other users can find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my module tag in web.config file.
It must be the full assembly name, not just the class name.
which in c# terms it can be the Assembly.FullName code.
For example i have a class which implemented IHttpModule like this:

```
public class StatisticsModule : IHttpModule
{
   public void Init(HttpApplication context)
   {
      context.ReleaseRequestState += context_ReleaseRequestState;
   }

   public void Dispose()
   { }
}
```

and this class placed in Shakib.Statistics Namespace, so for this example the Module Tag which should be in web.config and "modules" section, must be this:

```
<add name="Statistics" type="Shakib.Statistics.StatisticsModule, Shakib.Statistics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4d63664a8351e206" />
```